# I don't like SuperUser THAT Much! (Wrongly Reward Enthusiast Badge)

Tags: support, activity-badges

So, the people on SuperUser are really awesome and I'm glad you guys are keeping that place full of information.

However, I visited SuperUser today after my little plugin told me that I had visited SuperUser for 30 consecutive days. The thing is, I almost never visit SuperUser. So obviously I was surprised to learn that I got a badge for visiting a site I never go to.

I'm guessing this is not a program issue. So, my theory is that it has to do with this plugin I have on Google Chrome. Everyday, multiple times a day, it goes to my recent activity page on all 4 sites and finds out my rep.

Would this be how I got my badge?

Comment: Cheater.  Uniformed officers are on their way.

Comment: you think SU is smart enough to tell that it's a plugin requesting the page for processing and not the browser requesting it for rendering?  hahahahaha.  (seriously tho, enjoy your badge; eventually this functionality will go thru an API and (probably) won't count towards the badge.)

Comment: Why are people down voting this guy for reporting a bug ?

Comment: @bob: jealousy.  *a riot... is an uugly t'ing.  unt i t'ink it iz joost about time ve had vun!*

Comment: Same thing happens with top sites in Safari if you have them in there.

Comment: +1 - clearly the SO sites are all about clever answers to posed questions - using script to gain SO badges is an answer to a question that needed asking!  Now if anyone asks 'how can I get an 'enthusiast' badge the answer is ready.  Will you check back in on 1 June with information on how to get the 'fanatic' badge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, you have effectively scripted the badge.

Comment: I feel so happy...

Comment: @Jeff: Do you plan on 'fixing' this?

Comment: @joshhunt: How would *you* fix it? As far as I know the requests are entirely identical, there'd be no way to stop it without having many false positives.

Comment: @Phoshi, I guess you could ask the designed of the plugin to alter the user-agent, however this would then mean designing the site to skip certain behaviours for a certain user-agent, and is probably far too much work for a simple badge-fix.

Comment: I've always felt that the Enthusiast badge should be awarded for 30 consecutive days where you visited the site _and_ actually did something (left a commment, voted on something, _anything_ really beyond just getting a page view). Perhaps that should be a new badge " _Real_ Enthusiast".

Comment: @Kris *True* Enthusiast

Comment: Would this mean that a possible API to screw with some of the badges, by tricking all the badge-event triggers?

Comment: @Jeff: Is it true that the Fanatic badge does require additional activity of some sort? I think I remember seeing that somewhere, but not sure where.

Comment: @ivo, I think it would be easy for access through the api to not count towards all or some badges

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension/42268#42268) with the [Stack Overflow Notifier Chrome extension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension):

> I just wanted to point out a potential
>   issue (that you can't really fix) with
>   the extension. By doing a page scrape
>   of the different sites, you register a
>   hit for your account (makes sense) but
>   this caused me to get the Enthusiast
>   badge for my SU, SF, and Meta accounts
>   (I actually earned it properly for
>   SO). I know for a fact that I didn't
>   visit those sites consecutively for 30
>   days and they were just awarded 4
>   hours ago on all three sites at the
>   same time. I know I browse everyday
>   with Chrome so unless Jeff just
>   changed the rules, the unfortunate
>   page scrape awarded me the badges.

I'm guessing once an API is in place, the extension won't need to scrape the user page to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

When your plugin send request to your recent activity page, browser also send your cookies together, Its just a normal behavior, IMHO.

Edit: I just confirmed that you need to login (need your cookies) to get your recent activity list.

So, may be there is no way to avoid that. Just enjoy it!

Comment: So, given I open my browser everyday, I should eventually get a Fanatic badge on all 4 sites?

Comment: @chacha: what plugin is this, by the way?  i'm missing fanatic on SF & MSO...

Comment: @Chacha102, if you want, yes, you will. :D

Comment: @~quack: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension

Comment: I just realized that I didn't have Serverfault logged in. Well, now I do!